# How do I get support for a DELL Ubuntu laptop?

Tags: dell, laptop

Hopefully this experience will improve with DELL. I have a DELL M3800 Precision Workstation Laptop factory installed with Ubuntu.

When calling into DELL technical support (1-800-999-3355), when I tell them I need assistance with the DELL factory installed applications on my factory Ubuntu Linux laptop (basically any software problem) I get interesting answers like...

- We only support Windows
- You need to contact Canonical
- Call this number 1-866-982-8688 (which will not help)

How can I get technical support (which I paid for!) for my DELL Ubuntu laptop?

I am answering my own question below after a frustrating experience that took hours...

Comment: This fits in line with some of the horror stories I've heard over the years regarding Dell's support for Ubuntu as an OEM. If you still want to use pre-installed Ubuntu on your next OEM-supplied machine, then you may seriously want to consider a different supplier which focuses on supporting Ubuntu as their primary OS. [System76](https://system76.com/) and [ZaReason](https://zareason.com/) are examples of good choices of OEMs that support Ubuntu first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR
Call the "workstation group". They have a direct line 1-877-671-3355 and are knowledgeable about the Ubuntu laptops that DELL sells.**

They will help you directly if you have a hardware issue. If it is a software issue, they will open a ticket with special support that (I was told) has no direct line and they will call you back directly.

**Don't call 1-800-999-3355 for Ubuntu laptops**
Every time I call them, I get asked to call 1-866-982-8688. This number gives 2 options - to be connected with Ubuntu Advantage (which owning a DELL laptop does not entitle you to) or DELL DataSafe. Selecting DataSafe instructs you to call 1-877-218-1671. The techs there cannot support DELL laptops and will redirect you. I tried explaining this to the technicians at 1-800-999-3355, but they continued to insist I call the 1-866-982-8688 number.

UPDATE: I recently just called the 1-877-671-3355 and was instructed to call the 8688 number again. If DELL suggests that you call that number, inform them that it doesn't work. Hopefully they can look into this and get it sorted out internally.

UPDATE AGAIN: After much difficulty with DELL regarding Linux support, I remain very skeptical that the technicians or representative I speak to can accurately represent the Linux experience with DELL. For example, they may tell you that you can do something (such as use a DELL diagnostic tool or recommend updating drivers) with Windows, that simply isn't possible or sensical using Linux. I am very disappointed with this experience from DELL. I would not recommend it. DELL has technicians capable of supporting Linux, but chances are you wont get to speak with them or replies will be significantly delayed.

Be careful when speaking with DELL's sales especially.

Comment: Sound's like you've had a little experience with this!

Comment: @aikeru I am not able to call on 1877673355,They say to check the number.

Comment: @RahulRaj what you typed does not match what I have written above