# How do I fix UI lag on a Dell Precision 5520 when using a Bluetooth keyboard and mouse?

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, dell, performance

*EDIT: It appears the lag is caused only when using the bluetooth keyboard and mouse, which is still strange considering I've never had an issue with them before.*

My new Dell Precision 5520 is lagging.  For example, the mouse freezes for a second then jumps when doing something like opening a chromium tab.

It was like this out of the box.  How can I diagnose what's going wrong, or is the only recourse to send it back?

I have tried switching to the proprietary nVidia driver, as seen below, but no dice.

[image]

## Specs

- Ubuntu 16.04.2
- Kernel: 4.4.0-72-generic
- nVidia Quadro M1200
- Intel i7-7820HQ
- 16GB RAM
- 512GB SSD

Comment: what Ubuntu version are you on?

Comment: what's the output of `uname -r`

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh, ok, added that to the specs.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using Ubuntu pre-installed on [this system](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201610-25144/)? If this is the case, then you may try [contacting Dell support](https://askubuntu.com/q/595686/18612) for help with your issue directly from the OEM, or filing a bug report.

Comment: Thanks, actually, after using it for a couple days, the lag more subtle, so not worth contacting them now.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same laptop with the intel 8265 wifi radio.  I removed the radio and the UI freezes seem to be fixed.  Note that removing the card will disable bluetooth since the card has bluetooth and wifi.

I'm not sure if this is related, but the bluetooth firmware files aren't present in the kernel that ships with 16.10, and the firmware files for the wifi radio aren't present anywhere - it seems intel hasn't released them or the driver is loading the wrong files.  Dmesg shows the following:

`[    2.059624] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-24.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.059854] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8265-23.ucode failed with error -2`

There are similar errors for bluetooth.

The latest kernel firmware files for Ubuntu can be retrieved from here: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.165_all.deb.  After installing the package, run **sudo update-initramfs -u -k all**.

This file contains the bluetooth firmware files.  I'm not sure if installing it fixes any issues.

I've started a group for discussing issues with running Linux on this laptop: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dell-precision-5520-linux